# Create a 'Group Box' in Word Userform

Tags: forms, vba, excel, ms-word

"Group Box", for lack of a better word: I want areas in my user form which are visually different from others, with a different background colour and a frame around them, such as is possible to create using Frame controls. However, I want none of the events of Frame controls and none of their interaction with other controls in the form.

More particular, I want to be able to tab through all text, list, combo and check boxes, regardless of their location in 'Group Boxes', in fact also regardless of the possible location of their 'Group Box' within another 'Group Box'. Most of my controls have On Enter, On Exit, On Change and On Key even procedures attached to them which may re-direct the focus to any control on the form. Doing so under the constant interference of Frame controls with their events and rules - many of them not working correctly, none of them properly explained anywhere - is a gargantuan task. The easy way would be to have the visual design capabilities only, without the "intelligence" which assumes control in a way not compatible with my own plans.

Perhaps the one feature of frames which makes them unfit for my purposes is that they act as forms within the form, meaning they appoint an ActiveControl when activated which they refuse to release when another control takes the focus outside their own frame. It is inconvenient to prevent a first control's On Enter procedure from running when **any** control in a frame receives the focus (different for first and subsequent times), but it's a much bigger task to deal with the selected control's On Exit event which won't fire until the form is closed, meaning it is missed when the control optically loses the focus and a nuisance when it technically does.

Is there a control that fits my needs in MS Word? Or can the Frame control be stripped of its events in some way? Could I place a Text Box, for example, in front of a Frame control without it also being "within" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MS Word use a label with a background color.

For MS Access use the rectangle Object behind the controls.

First make the form background a grey color. Then add subforms(ms access) and rectangles to segment the controls.

The end effect is it looking like a paneled interface.

Comment: Where do I find the rectangle? Are you talking about MS Word? I'm using version 2010.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read correctly, for some reason I thought u were using MS Access (not MS Word). You can use a label with a background color as likely the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes! That's what I "discovered" years ago and forgot. Please modify your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Variatus a label with `SpecialEffect=fmSpecialEffectEtched` and an empty `Caption` looks just like what I think you're afer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Frame control. Place the other controls first, then place the Frame control, and move it to the back. This should look visually identical to having the controls in the Frame.

Comment: That's *visually* sound, but overlapping controls *technically* isn't. But upvoted for answering OP's question quite exactly as it was asked - "Could I place a Text Box, for example, in front of a Frame control without it also being "within" it?"

Comment: How can I move the frame to the back? I'm using MS Word 2010.

Comment: I've never actually used this in a form, but noticed that it would work while "messing around". What are the pitfalls?

Comment: @Mat's Mug: What is the technical reason for overlapping controls not being "technically sound"?

Comment: @Rich Holton -The immediate "pitfall" is that my version of Word doesn't seem to offer the capability of placing controls in front of each other.

Comment: @Variatus hmm, in older versions of Windows / Office it was a problem IIRC. After some quick research it appears fixed. Still, container controls are designed and meant to *contain* child controls; there's a bit of a logical relationship between the controls.

Comment: @Variatus: I'm working on it right now. It isn't quite what I remember, but I'll let you know when I figure it out.

Comment: @Variatus: I'm sorry, I get make it work the way I remember. Either my memory is false, or something has changed. In VBE, under the Format menu, the last item is Order (I think). The sub-menu gives options to move-to-back, Move-to-front, etc. It's equivalent to the zorder method. But apparently, you can't use this on a Frame. It may work on a Text Box behind other controls though. I didn't try that.

Comment: @Rich Holton: Thanks for your effort. Your memory is undiminishedly perfect :-). I didn't even know it was there. But having chewed on this for a week I was so relieved to be reminded to use labels for this I threw out my frames without a minute's delay. Didn't stop to even think of what they might do to my grey hair if they could be moved to the back. After I recover I shall try. Thank you for your support.